# combineLatest() function on mainThread

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I want to combine 2 observables and execute "combine function" on AndroidSchedules.mainThread(). I've added .observeOn(AndroidSchedules.mainThread()) but I am still getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread".

```
Observable<List<Post>> animateCameraAndGetPostsByProjection = Observable.combineLatest(
            mapObservableProvider.getMapReadyObservable(),
            LocationService.getUpdatedOrLastKnownLocation(this),
            (googleMap, location) -> {
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),15);
                googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                return googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
            })
            .flatMap(vr -> new RestService().getApi().getPostsByMapProjection(vr.farLeft.latitude,vr.farLeft.longitude,vr.nearRight.latitude,vr.nearRight.longitude))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: Where does the error point to? It is possible the API requires you to call it on the main thread and not the reception of the final result.

Comment: error points to googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate). I know that this function should run on the main thread, but I don't know how to set thread of combine function.

Comment: Put the observeOn onto both sources, when both have values, the function will be executed on the main thread.

Comment: I need get location in the new thread, so I can't observeOn on main thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, you have to pair up the two values and send it over to the main thread.

```
Observable<List<Post>> animateCameraAndGetPostsByProjection =  Observable.combineLatest(
    mapObservableProvider.getMapReadyObservable(),
    LocationService.getUpdatedOrLastKnownLocation(this),
    (googleMap, location) -> Pair.of(googleMap, location)
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.map(pair -> {
     CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
         .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(pair.second.getLatitude(),
              pair.second.getLongitude()),15);
     pair.first.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
     return googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();         
})
.flatMap(vr -> new RestService().getApi()
   .getPostsByMapProjection(vr.farLeft.latitude,vr.farLeft.longitude,
        vr.nearRight.latitude,vr.nearRight.longitude)
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: What is the point in observeOn mainThread 2 times? And where to subscribeOn?

Comment: The RestService may go async again and emit from a background thread. observeOn makes sure we get to react to the data on the main thread.

Comment: How to modify combineLatest? For example, remove one of Observables?